# Avoiding repetition with left-right children of tree in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, idioms

I wanted to avoid repeating my if-else twice (once for left, once for right, identically), so I did this, which feels very unidiomatic:

```
MovieNode** child = title < parent->title ? &parent->left : &parent->right;
if(*child)
    parent = *child;
else
    *child = new MovieNode(ranking, title, releaseYear, quantity);
```

What's the proper way to do this?

[btw this is why I prefer Haskell XD, I would just do `parent = child`]

Comment: So what are you thinking of to be unidiomatic?

Comment: I think there is an error in your example code: `*child` is of type `MovieNode*`, not `MovieNode`, so the last line doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh ya, I should have new

Comment: Why are using double pointers?

Comment: Unrelated, once I wrote a binary tree, and frustrated for the same reason, I switched to `Node* children[2];`, and it was amazing. `Node* child = parent->children[title > parent->title];` No branches.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are writing an iterative insert algorithm for your binary tree.  What you have is concise and acceptable, although admittedly looks a bit abnormal.

The way I would normally write such an algorithm is like this:

```
// start from your root node, parent must not be NULL
MovieNode ** current = &parent;

// find an appropriate empty leaf
while (*(current = (title < (*current)->title ? &(*current)->left : &(*current)->right)));

// assign to the empty leaf
(*current) = new MovieNode(ranking, title, releaseYear, quantity);
```

EDIT: Minor but important update to the while() loop made after I actually tested and proved this out in a real program.  It is good to go now.

Comment: (hint: `MoveNode*&`)

Comment: @MooingDuck that sounded like a good idea until I tried it.  The problem is that once a reference is assigned, you cannot re-assign.  So, after assigning current to parent, subsequent assignments just change the parent.  Maybe you had other code in mind, interested to see how this loop could look a little cleaner without all the derefs.